Using an async preHandler function on @fastify/http-proxy creates a FastifyError: Reply was already sent
I have the current code for proxying.
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })
const fastifyHttpProxy = require('@fastify/http-proxy')

fastify.register(fastifyHttpProxy, {
  upstream: ...,
  prefix: '/',
  http2: false,
  rewritePrefix: ...,
  preValidation: (request, reply, done) => {
    // Some validation code
    done()
  },
  preHandler: (request, reply, next) => {
    // Some handler
    request.raw.url = `${request.raw.url}/some-path`
    next()
  }
})

fastify.listen({ port: 3000 }, (err, address) => {
  if (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
  fastify.log.info(`Server listening on ${address}`)
})


But when I add an async operation to my preHandler function, it returns this error.
err":{"type":"FastifyError","message":"Reply was already sent, did you forget to \"return reply\" in \"//app1/index.html\" (GET)?","stack":"FastifyError: Reply was already sent, did you forget to \"return reply\" in \"//app1/index.html\" (GET)?\n    at Reply.send 

To reproduce, just add a simple Promise.resolve.
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })
const fastifyHttpProxy = require('@fastify/http-proxy')

fastify.register(fastifyHttpProxy, {
  upstream: ...,
  prefix: '/',
  http2: false,
  rewritePrefix: ...,
  preValidation: (request, reply, done) => {
    // Some validation code
    done()
  },
  preHandler: async (request, reply, next) => {
    // Some handler, e.g. adding path
    await Promise.resolve(1)
    request.raw.url = `${request.raw.url}/some-path`
    next()
  }
})

fastify.listen({ port: 3000 }, (err, address) => {
  if (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
  fastify.log.info(`Server listening on ${address}`)
})


What is causing this and how can I perform async operations in preHandler (I want to use it to do some authentication)?

Remove the next arg from the preHandeler function: do not mix async/await with callbacks.

@ManuelSpigolon Thank you, it worked. This was not mentioned in the docs, how did you figure it out?

You need to remove the next callback in the preHandler function to make it works:
  preHandler: async (request, reply) => {
    // Some handler, e.g. adding path
    await Promise.resolve(1)
    request.raw.url = `${request.raw.url}/some-path`
  }

The API is documented here: https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Hooks/#prehandler
meanwhile the "do not mix async/await and callback" is explained at: https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Hooks/#respond-to-a-request-from-a-hook

It is important to not mix callbacks and async/Promise, otherwise the hook chain will be executed twice.

Plus: I wrote the only Fastify book out there, checkout my profile if you need it
